# svg elements - scroll to/ centering

Tags: svg, centering

I've an svg dynamically created on a page. As things "happen" (user clicks) the svg expands and collapses certain elements. It may fit in the viewport, it may not. In the case that its too big to fit on a page, the user must scroll to where s(he) wants to go/see. Now this is fine, however I have a requirement that the last element "selected" becomes the center of the page/viewport. i.e. If they click on an item, thats what they need to see *without* scrolling.

Could anybody tell me the best way to attack this. I've googled around but can't find what I'm looking for (though I'm not long at all this so I might have been searching the wrong stuff).

Is there a way to do this purely programmatically with javascript? Or am I obliged to pass by CSS to get the solution I want. Any tips/links/advice much appreciated.

thanks and have a nice day

G

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar thing and I used the `viewBox` property to handle this. You could also use a wrapping `<g>` element, which you translate. However, from my point of view the basic approach is the same and you basically need to do two things:

1. keep track of the `x` and `y` offset and the dimensions of the viewport. (Using the `viewBox` will give you that »for free«)
2. Compute the center of the Element. Therefore I used the `getBoundingClientRect()`method which yields the AABB of of the Element in absolute coordinate space, relative to top-left edge of the whole page.

With these things, all that remains is to calculate the vector from the viewport center to the object's center.

[Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) you can find the reference of the `viewBox` and [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html) a nice tutorial about it, because it can be a bit confusing at the beginning.

Another pro for the »viewBox« approach is: There is no dependency on special DOM elements, it just works on the root `<svg>` element. I once implemented both methods, I started out using a wrapping `<g>` element, what worked fine but gave me some performance issues. So I decided to change and use the `viewBox`, with the result, that the performance in Firefox grow, but slowed down in Chromium.

**Edit**

[Here you can find a little](http://jsfiddle.net/eqdp6ey9/4/) fiddle, that outlines the approach. But be aware of the following: `getBoundingClientRect()` yields the position of the Element on the whole Page, so if your `<svg>` is not positioned at (0,0) (top: 0px; left: 0px), than that will include the offset of the svg itself. The offset of the `viewBox` must not include this offset, so you need to cancel that out somehow. For sake of simplicity I just used the client Bounding Rect of the SVG, what works because there are no transformations applied.

Comment: thanks a million for that. I think we'll be doing exactly as you suggest. Cheers